# Grep, ignore warnings

Tags: search, grep

I am trying to find the installation directory of a particular package. I have a certain keyword using which I am trying to find a particular file.

During grep, I only want to include **cpp or h** file type. I do not want the grep to show **warnings** like *Permission Denied* or  *Could not find the Directory*.
I just want it to display matched files, nothing else. Please suggest how can I do this?

At present I am using

```
grep "My term" -ir --exclude-dir="\.svn" --include=*.{cpp,h} ./
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Those warnings are directed to the `stderr` stream, as opposed to the standard out file descriptor.  You can silence the stderr output by adding `2>/dev/null` to the end of your command.

Comment: Te be more specific ```find . 2>/dev/null | grep 404.html``` is what a command would look like

Comment: Not the end of the command, but at the start of the command. (arch linux)                
                                   
example :           `2>/dev/null ifconfig | grep inet`        
This will show you your local ip without any error.

Answer (score 34):

More directly than filtering the warnings you can disable them by adding `-s`:

```
grep "My term" -sir --exclude-dir="\.svn" --include=*.{cpp,h} ./
```

There are some compatibility issues with this option. However, this shouldn't be a problem for personal use.

> -s, --no-messages:
>                 Suppress  error messages about nonexistent or unreadable files.  Portability note: unlike GNU grep, 7th Edition Unix grep did
>   not conform to POSIX, because it
>                 lacked -q and its -s option behaved like GNU grep's -q option.  USG-style grep also lacked -q but its -s option behaved like
>   GNU grep.  Portable shell scripts
>                 should avoid both -q and -s and should redirect standard and error output to /dev/null instead.  (-s is specified by POSIX.)

Comment: I just installed 13.04 and I am getting the errors which I was not getting with 12.04. Could it be that something changed? I thought it was cool that grep would stop warning about files being directories since in most cases I just don't care!

Comment: Sorry, I am still on 12.10, so I cannot confirm this.

Answer (score 5):

I used to get a ton of annoying messages like this:

```
grep: commands: Is a directory
grep: events: Is a directory
grep: views: Is a directory
```

The reason is that the `--directories` flag is defaulted to `read`. I changed it to `recurse`; if you don't want it to automatically do a recursive search you can use `skip` instead.

The easiest way to handle this all the time is to set it in an environment variable. In `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` depending on your distro:

```
export GREP_OPTIONS='--directories=recurse'
```

Now it automatically suppresses those messages any time I use grep.

Another option is the `--no-messages` flag, shorthand `-s`. This will also get rid of the `Is a directory` messages, but it also suppresses other messages which might be more useful. For example, if you're doing a nested search in `*/*/*` and no such file of that pattern exists, it won't tell you that.

Comment: good explanaition

Comment: The downside of the `--directories=recurse` option, of course, is that it always performs a recursive grep, even when you know that you just want to grep files in the current folder. Problematic in an era of `node_modules`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach instead of doing `grep` recursively with `-ir`  would be to let `find` command (which is recursive by default) handle the permissions with `-readable` flag and path's to exclude  with `-not -path "*.svn*"` flags, and then pass the file to `grep`. Excluding directories is done via `-type f` for finding only regular files.

```
$ find . -not -path "*.svn*" -type f -name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.h"  -readable -exec grep "my terms" "{}" \;
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing recursive searches in specific files, you are much better off using `ack-grep`. The syntax here would be:

```
ack-grep -i "My term" --cpp --h
```

To remove the permission error messages, you may want to run the same command with `sudo`:

```
ack-grep -i "My term" --cpp --h
```

But eventually, if you want to search installed packages, look at those various options: https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu%20search%20inside%20installed%20packages